# sms url scheme not working on IOS5

Tags: web-applications, ios5, mobile-webkit

In my web app targeted to iphone and android, I have a "TEXT ME" button which when clicked, leads the user to sms with number and body prefilled. This works fine in iphone prior to ios 5.
In IOS 5, clicking on the button does not lead to sms applicatin. Is there any change in IOS 5 for sms url scheme which i am missing. Here is what i am using
sms:2062142930?body=Mobile%20Inquiry&

Thanx
zAfar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try this without a message body. The Apple URL scheme reference [1] says this about text links:

- The sms scheme is used to launch the Text application. The format for URLs of this type is “sms:”, where  is an optional parameter that specifies the target phone number of the SMS message. This parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters. The URL string must not include any message text or other information*

So while this may have worked in the past they may have enforced the last part (must not include any message text), probably to mitigate some misuse.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf