# Sending sms in air with body

Tags: actionscript-3, air, sms

I was searching to how to send a sms in air. I found this code while googling:

```
var callURL:String="sms:0-123-456-7890";
var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
navigateToURL(targetURL);
```

Its working, but how to add a body text to it and can it be used to send sms to multiple numbers???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's link to standarts of using URI schemes https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724#section-2.2.

But unfortunately looks like there is no way to implement this since neither iOS nor Android supports this feature in full way.

Here's link for Android ussue about it http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12142
And here's answer on SO about iOS [sms url scheme not working on IOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414986/sms-url-scheme-not-working-on-ios5)